# html li horizontal image css code messes with my nav bar

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a div that contains 4 image. I'm using the  tag and li and a as I can easily change the images and don't need to make a div for each image. My website is suppose to look like their are three images in a row. One of my images when you hover over it it shows the final image. which is the middle one. I have to used div class for the middle image. The problem is in my css i use a comma for ul, li which messes up my nav bar but aligns my images perfectly.

Here's my code so far:
HTML:

```
    <div class="n-games_img.contain">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a target="_blank" href="https://www.callofduty.com/wwii">
                    <img src="cod_ww2.png"; style="width:450px; left:19px;">
                </a>
            </li>
            <li style="left: 420px;">
                <a class="destiny" target="_blank" href="https://www.destinythegame.com/">

                <img src="destiny2_news_text.png"; style="width:450px;">
                <img class="destiny_top" src="destiny2_news.png"; style="width:450px;">
                </a>
            </li>
            <li style="left: 800px">
                <a target="_blank" href="https://www.ea.com/games/starwars/battlefront/battlefront-2">
                    <img src="starwars_battlefront2.png"; style="width:450px;">
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>

    </div>
```

CSS:

```
       .n-games_img.contain{
    height: 350px;
    width:100%;
}

.n-games_img.contain ul{
    white-space: nowrap;


}

.n-games_img.contain ul , li { //bad code//
    clear:both;
    list-style:none;
    position: absolute;
    display: inline;
    float:left;
    max-width:450px;
}
.destiny{
    position: absolute;
    max-width:450px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.destiny img{
  list-style: none;
    position: absolute;
    display: inline;
    float:left;
    max-width:450px;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;    
    transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}

.destiny_top:hover{
    opacity:0;
}
```

Comment: .n-games_img.contain ul , li;
li after ',' means that this rules will work for all tag li on your page. For second li you can use special identificator like class name

Comment: is their any way I could do it without class name

Comment: n-games_img.contain - bad name for class name - use '_' or '-'

Comment: .n-games_img.contain ul  li why you use ','? where i can saw all off your code?

Comment: its in a note pad ++

Comment: what do you want to see exactly

Comment: notepad)))  you use this in the css file. .n-games_img.contain ul , li -  this entry means that you use these rules for two different items

Comment: Sorry i should re word the thread im asking after I change the code it messes up my tags and goes out of line with the div and becomes verticle

Comment: can you give a fiddle with your full code?

Comment: ok im making it now

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=FVBM4K6Fw1 this has style for three html pages

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ur5b2p5u/1/ - check this

Comment: join the js fiddle

Comment: hello can join the jsfiddle to chat

Comment: give me your link

Comment: the problem is the images dont overlap

Comment: join the one you made for me

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ur5b2p5u/1/#&togetherjs=eBUocjp9r4